# Is there an excel formula or VBA code that merges cells based on certain conditions?

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, merge, find

I have a table that looks like this:

[image: 1]

Notice in cell B5 - it states the length of the class as 1.30hrs.

Yet it does not fill in the cell to the right -- cell C5.

I am trying to type a formula that finds the length of class and merges to the next cell over if it fulfills that requirement.

So with the example above, cell B5 states the class length of 1.5 hours, with a start time of 9:00. So B5 should merge with C5 so that it spans from 9am - 10:30am (cells B3 AND C3).

I have tried using the CONCATENATE function with FIND and IF statements, but there is no formula to merge cells.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: No formula will be able to do this.  You will need vba.

Comment: You could use formula based conditional formatting to colour the cells, but you'll need code as @ScottCraner states to do a merge.

Comment: I am not too familiar with VBA, would any of you know any resources to point me towards to get a good start on writing this code? @ScottCraner @Nathan_Sav?

Comment: You can start here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/library-reference/concepts/getting-started-with-vba-in-office VBA is the coding language of Microsoft Office, it is very powerfull compared to only working with formulas and you can do almost anything you want.

Comment: You could *imitate* merged cells using conditional formatting. Where the text is identical to the cell to the left, make the text the same colour as the background and do **not** draw the left-border. You'd just have to accept that the text will appear at the far left of the 'merged cell(s)'.

Comment: @CLR that seems like a good alternative. I cannot seem to figure out VBA...thing is I have already set the table to conditional formatting so that certain course numbers are highlighted a specific color depending on the type of course it is. (ex: Finance is a teal blue) how would I go about re-condtionally formatting it so it merges to the adjacent cell if it has a specific length? Thanks

Comment: I'd probably have a second hidden tab that has all the workings, and set the conditional formatting to use that data to decide the formatting.